# Как посчитать количество строк в нужном формате

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть база в которой дата прописана в таком формате: 2022-05-06 00:11:59
Нужно определить количество строк с сегодняшней датой без времени: 2022-05-06
Как правильно написать запрос?

Этот не работает:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "SELECT date, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') as newdate FROM chat WHERE newdate = '$date'";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
$rowsCountchat = $result->num_rows; // количество полученных строк
}
```

Comment: че за язык? php? добавь метку тогда. Либо просто оставь скл-запрос вроде его достаточно для ответа на вопрос

Comment: видимо `select count(*) from chat where date = DATE(now())`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE(назв.столбца с "2022-05-06 00:11:50"),
       COUNT(назв.этого же столбца)
FROM назв.таблицы
WHERE DATE(назв.этого же столбца)=CURDATE()  /* если текущая дата* /
GROUP BY 1;
```

Выдаст два столбца: дату в формате `2022-05-10` и количество.

Если нужна не сегодняшняя, а конкретная дата, то `CURDATE()` в запросе нужно поменять на неё, например, `2022-06-05`.